# Dynamic number of evaluations on a where (lambda)

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda

I'm new to Entity Framework, LINQ and lambda expressions. I need to do a search over a user's table, and I need to emulate one that already exists on a desktop application. This search gives only 1 text field, and then it takes anything that you put in it and creates a "contains" query on different users' attributes like name, last name, username, etc. The most important part is that if you put two or more words in then the search makes the query search for different words.

Example:

If I search for "ju pe" I will get "Perez, Juan", this works by the identification of blank spaces.

Using regular SQL I can build a regular string containing the query, but how can I do that using lambda?

In other words, how can I get a dynamic number of "evaluations" on the `.where()`? Like `.Where(EV1 || EV2 || EVn)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is neat library called LinqKit which contains [predicatebuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Sample code:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True <User> ();

predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Name.Contains("ju"));
predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Name.Contains("pe"));
// etc ...

Users.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);
```

You can and/or as much as you like.

Comment: nice, just run into a new problem, im using a join:    var resultado = db_hms.Users
                            .Join(db_hms.v_natural_person_short, ur => ur.id_employee, np => np.id_natural_person, (ur, np) => new { Users = ur, Natural_Person = np })
                            .Where(r => r.Users.id_user.Contains(search) || r.Natural_Person.name_full.Contains(search))
                            .Select(s => new { user_id = s.Users.id_user, nombre = s.Natural_Person.name_full })
                            .ToList();

Comment: whats exactly the problem?

Comment: PredicateBuilder need a type example: var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True <User> (), i have an anonimus Type

Comment: you can define new type and use it instead of anonymous type. im afraid that it's the only option

Comment: working on it, removed the join (create a view), problems whit predicatebuilder and null values, searching...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using simple Linq by building a complex `Where` predicate, if I understand you correctly.  Please let me know if I misunderstood you!   Let's say you have a string `searchTermInput` and `users`, an `IEnumerable<User>` for some type `User` with a `Name` string property.  Then you can write:

```
users.Where(user => searchTermInput.Split(' ')
                    .All(searchTerm => user.Name.Contains(searchTerm)));
```

In other words: for each user, check if that user's name contains every one of the search terms and filter it out if it does not.

Comment: does this qualify as EF expression?

Comment: No - LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method Split. Question was about EF.